# Significance / Usefulness / purpose of new jQuery.ajax way which returns the jqXHR object

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.5

as of 1.5/1.51 version of jQuery we can make an ajax request like this

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({ url: "example.php" })
    .success(function() { alert("success"); })
    .error(function() { alert("error"); })
    .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.complete(function(){ alert("second complete"); });
```

1> 
i am still looking for some example/ demos / some info to know what  significant purpose does this way of doing jQuery.ajax serves that previous way was not serving

2> How much useful is this jqXHR object.

3> Iam looking for some practical usefulness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, jQuery themselves [say](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> The $.ajax() function returns the XMLHttpRequest object that it creates. Normally jQuery handles the creation of this object internally, but a custom function for manufacturing one can be specified using the xhr option. The returned object can generally be discarded, but does provide a lower-level interface for observing and manipulating the request. In particular, calling .abort() on the object will halt the request before it completes.

So if for some reason you need to create your own XMLHTTPRequest object and send it in to $.ajax, this provides a way to get that object back after the request.

Answer (score 1):

Well from the looks of it, it seems they improved the wrapping of the XMLHttpRequest object,
and as you stated in your question, now you can actually stack methods for the different ajax events.

By the way, if you haven't already noticed, you can see they have not changed the wrap completely, so there will be backward compatibility with old $.ajax code.

I guess this whole improvement is to provide the $.ajax method, an dom event like system that jQuery already offers, just for the events.

So bottom line, there isn't anything special here besides stacking methods for the ajax events.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest practical example for me is that you can consider to use sometime simplified form of `$.ajax` like [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), because now you can use `error` handler also with `$.getJSON`:

```
$.getJSON(
    'myServerUrl',
    {param1: "foo", param2: "bar"},
    function(data) {})
 .error(function() { alert("error"); });
```

Additionally you asked for more informations. Here two links: [Using Deferreds in jQuery 1.5](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/) and [PROMISES FROM A TO J](http://jaubourg.net/) which explains the basis of the new changes in `$.ajax`.